# I keep getting error 3061 Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have tried adding brackets to my stated parameters to show that they are separate but I still get the error, I checked all the "&" but to no avail.
Here is the code. Thanks in advance.

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function SendMail()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim emailTo As String
Dim emailSubject As String
Dim emailText As String

Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outlookStarted As Boolean


On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If outApp Is Nothing Then
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
outlookStarted = True
End If

Set db = CurrentDb
            strSQL = "SELECT DATE, COMPANY, CUSTOMER, EMAIL, FUP, [SAMPLES 
REQUESTED]" & _
                        " FROM Sample Query WHERE DATE = Date()"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
Do Until rs.EOF

emailTo = rs.Fields("EMAIL").Value

emailSubject = "Proposal Follow Up"
If IsNull(rs.Fields("COMPANY").Value) Then
    emailSubject = emailSubject & " for " & _
                    rs.Fields("COMPANY").Value & " " & 
rs.Fields("CUSTOMER").Value
End If

emailText = Trim("Hello " & rs.Fields("COMPANY").Value) & "!" & vbCrLf


emailText = emailText & _
            "Hello, " & rs.Fields("Name").Value & _
            rs.Fields("CUSTOMER").Value & " ordered " & rs.Fields("SAMPLES 
REQUESTED").Value & _
            " on " & rs.Fields("Date").Value & " its been about a month. A 
follow up would be good about now."

Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
outMail.To = emailTo
outMail.Subject = emailSubject
outMail.Body = emailText
outMail.Send

                rs.Edit
                rs("FUP") = Now()
                rs.Update


rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

If outlookStarted Then
outApp.Quit
End If

Set outMail = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: And you should put `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module. That will force you to declare all variables you use, which has the advantage of letting you know when you misspell something...

Comment: @CindyMeister Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

Comment: Create a new query in the Access query designer, switch to SQL View and paste in this SQL text: `SELECT q.DATE, q.COMPANY, q.CUSTOMER, q.EMAIL, q.FUP, q.[SAMPLES REQUESTED]  FROM [Sample Query] AS q WHERE q.DATE = Date()`  What happens when you attempt to run that query?

Comment: @HansUp It runs fine

Comment: OK.  Revise your VBA to load the exact same text into your `strSQL` variable.  And add `Debug.Print strSQL` afterward.  If you run into any other SQL error when you run the code, go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there) to inspect the actual SQL you're asking the db engine to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss brackets around the reserved word *Date*:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [DATE], COMPANY, CUSTOMER, EMAIL, FUP, [SAMPLES REQUESTED]" & _
         " FROM [Sample Query] WHERE [DATE] = Date()"
```

Comment: but now im getting a Expected 2  instead of one at the the same line, probably involving the 2 lines above strSQL = "SELECT [DATE], COMPANY, CUSTOMER, EMAIL, FUP, [Name], [SAMPLES REQUESTED]" & _
         " FROM Sample Query WHERE [DATE] = Date()"

Comment: Sorry, the table name needs brackets too, as it contains a space. But typically, the error indicates a missing or misspelled field name.

Answer (score 1):

*Date* is a protected word in Access.  If you need to use that exact field name, put it in brackets like Gustav suggests.  You can also rename the field, like *TheDate* or *DateStart*.

Here's a full list of protected words:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286335/list-of-reserved-words-in-access-2002-and-in-later-versions-of-access